# Looking for an equation that roughly generates the given graph

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I would like to precursor this with the fact that I am in no way a mathematician. Anyways, I am looking help finding an equation, series of equations, or any information on a good starting point for generating a graph roughly like the one in the picture below. Also, I'd like to be able to rotate it around 0,0. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Example of what I would roughly like to generate:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a parametric equation?

Comment: Could you say in which document you have found this curve ? It could indicated which domain is to be invoked... (complex function theory, projection on a 3D curve, ...).

Answer (score 2):

The parametric equations
$$x=3sin(t-\frac{\pi}{4})+2sin(3t-\frac{\pi}{4})$$
$$y=3cos(t+\frac{\pi}{6})+2cos(3t+\frac{\pi}{6})$$
$$0≤t≤2\pi$$
gets you 
[image]

I arrived at the numbers largely through trial and error, but started from this observation: from your sketch, if you look at the movement along just, say, the $x$-axis it describes a sine wave modulated by another sine. In other words, two sine functions added together. Using Geogebra, it was then a matter of playing with the various parameters to shift the sine curves with respect to one another until getting something approximating your sketch. No doubt there are more formal approaches.

Comment: [+1] Your solution is good. I have given an "answer" which was in fact a commentary on yours... I am at present looking for a very different solution where the given self-crossing curve would be a projection of a 3D (non self-crossing) curve...

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @robert timmer-arends is good.

Here is a "a posteriori" possible full justification.

In fact one can relate the curve obtained to a general family, those of [hypotrochoids](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypotrochoid.html), here given by:

$$z=5e^{\color{red}{1}it}-ae^{\color{red}{3}it} \ \ \iff \ \ \begin{cases}x&=&5\cos(t)-a\cos(3t)\\y&=&5\sin(t)-a\sin(3t) \end{cases}\tag{1}$$

represented on the left of the figure for values of $a$ ranging from $0$ to $5$. For the ratio $\color{red}{3/1}$, see remark below.

These curves can in a second step be "skewed" using a linear transform. Here (see the right part of the figure corresponding to $a=5$), we have taken:

$$\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\ \ 1&-\tfrac12\\-1& \ \ \ 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$

Plugging (1) into (2), no surprise that we find expressions close to those of Robert.

Remark: The ratio $\color{red}{3/1}$ in (1) is compulsory for having $3-1=2$ loops. Had we taken $z=5e^{\color{red}{1}it}-ae^{\color{red}{13}it}$, we would have generated $13-1=12$ loops.

[image]